# Fading out objects with EdgesHelper material

Tags: three.js

I have a Three.js scene with a building model, which is made up of several objects. I have a need to show and hide the model at different times, and I can do that by using object.visible=false; inside a scene.traverse loop, but I would like to fade it in and out rather than just making it pop in and out.

I have tried setting transparent to true on the material, and then decreasing the opacity over time, and that works for the main mesh object, but not for the edgesHelper object. They don't change at all.

I cannot fade the scene because there are other objects that need to stay visible.

Is there a way to fade out an edgesHelper object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the opacity of `EdgesHelper` by using a pattern like so:

```
var eh = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh );
eh.material.opacity = 0.5;
eh.material.transparent = true;
scene.add( eh );
```

three.js r.76

Comment: This is so obvious now, yet I didn't try it because transparent isn't listed as a property of edgesHelper (neither is material for that matter) in the Three.js documentation.